# See Eclipse IDE component source code

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

It seems that you can hover mouse over any Eclipse IDE component and press a keyboard shortcut to see the component source code. What is that keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you're talking about the "[Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy)": Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> for the Plug-In Spy and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for the Menu Spy. (or enter "Spy" in the Quick Access field to see your specific shortcut, if it should differ).